# Interfaces and Generics

Tags: delphi, generics, interface, delphi-2009

I have problems to get generics to work in the following scenario:

Delphi provides the interface IComparable:

```
IComparable <T> = interface
  function CompareTo (Value : T) : Integer;
end;
```

I add another interface IPersistent:

```
IPersistent = interface
  function  ToString : String;
  procedure FromString (const Str : String);
end;
```

One example of a class implementing both interfaces:

```
TComparableString = class (TInterfacedObject, IComparable <String>, IPersistent)
strict private
  FValue : String;
public
  function  CompareTo (Value : String) : Integer;
  function  ToString : String;
  procedure FromString (const Str : String);
end;
```

Now for another generic class that has two interface constraints:

```
ISortIndex <VALUE_TYPE : IPersistent, IComparable> = interface
  ...
end;
```

And finally one implementation of that interface:

```
TSimpleSortIndex <VALUE_TYPE : IPersistent, IComparable> = class (TInterfacedObject, ISortIndex <VALUE_TYPE>)

  ...
end;
```

Now when I try to declare a sort index like that:

```
FSortIndex : ISortIndex <TComparableString>;
```

I get an error message

```
[DCC Error] Database.pas(172): E2514 Type parameter 'VALUE_TYPE' must support  interface 'IComparable'
```

I tried several things but can't get it to work.

Anyone in for some help? Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `TComparableString` class doesn't implement the non-generic `IComparable` interface, so it doesn't satisfy the type constraint. You'll have to either change the constraint or implement `IComparable`.

Changing the constraint is probably the easiest way forward. I don't really know Delphi, but see if this works:

```
ISortIndex <VALUE_TYPE : IPersistent, IComparable<VALUE_TYPE>> = interface

TSimpleSortIndex <VALUE_TYPE : IPersistent, IComparable<VALUE_TYPE>> = 
    class (TInterfacedObject, ISortIndex <VALUE_TYPE>)
```

EDIT: I hadn't noticed that your `TComparableString` implemented `IComparable<String>` rather than `IComparable<TComparableString>`. Is that deliberate? Usually something is comparable to other instances of itself, not to a different type.

You could introduce *another* type parameter to `ISortIndex`/`TSimpleSortIndex` to indicate the type that `VALUE_TYPE` should be comparable to - but I *suspect* it's more sensible to change `TComparableString`.

Comment: I tried that. It results in the following error: "E2514 Type parameter 'VALUE_TYPE' must support interface 'IComparable<SortIndex.TComparableString>'"

Comment: I really meant to use TComparableString there instead of String. Everything seems to work fine now. Thanks for the quick and precise help!